# how to pass javascript code as POST or GET fields in php

Tags: php, javascript, browser

I am trying to pass javascript code from 1 page of my website to another page (on submit of a form)

The user enters an adsense code which is a javascript code like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "nnnnddddnnnd";
/* abcdabcd */
google_ad_slot = "61748777731443";
google_ad_width = 123;
google_ad_height = 234;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

I want to pass this javascript from page 1 as a normal from field using get or post to page 2. When I use GET the browser shows permission denied and when I use POST there is no output of the javascript on the page 2

How can I do this?

Additional info:

the user enters the code in a text box on page 1 and presses submit then page1 is directed to page 2 where I want to use this JS on page 2 but I am unable to pass it even with POST

CODE

```
<form id="tryform" class="a-center" action="page2.php" method="post" onSubmit="return checkurl();" >
    <input name="ref" type="hidden" value="" />            
    <div >
        Enter the URL of the web page <br/>
        <span class="input-box full-width" style="float:center">
        <input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="Paste your website URL here"                  
            onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Paste your website URL here'}"
            onfocus="if(this.value=='Paste your website URL here'){this.value=''}"/>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div >
        Place your code here:
        <br/>
        <textarea id="adcode" name="adcode" cols="60" rows="8"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="button" name="B1" value="B1" >b1</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: POST is the way to go. Show the code you are using to output the data

Comment: How does the user enter that code?

Comment: the user enters the code in a text box on page 1 and presses submit then page1 is directed to page 2 where I want to use this JS on page 2 but I am unable to pass it even with POST

Comment: Do you have some sort of security software blocking POST data like this?  A lot of shared hosting companies will block user input data containing script tags and what not.

Comment: POST, definitely.  Don't use GET unless you want things to be bookmarkable.

Comment: We can't help you until we see the code. If you say "Doc, my ankle hurts."  How is the doc to know that you've just lost your leg at the knee?

Comment: @brad ya I am using shared hosting at hostgator is there any work around? thanks

Comment: As others have said, post your code first.  Just do a `print_r($_POST)` on the script that is supposed to receive POST data, and see what you get.  If blank, try posting some normal text.  If normal text works, and script tags don't, call Hostgator.

Comment: @Graham The code is simple .. 1 form which has a textbox and a submit button ...the user enters the JS in text box and presses submit button ...the page is directed to page 2 where I require the JS.

Comment: @yuvraj - work around for what?  You haven't shown us the problem yet.

Comment: @Brad ya normal text is shown on page 2 only JS is not shown

Comment: Ok going to post the code in a min

Comment: posted the code ... any workaround?

Comment: if i remove <script type="text/javascript"> the rest of the JS is then visible on page 2

Comment: I see no PHP.  Show us your PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you `str_replace('<', '&lt;', $formelement)` ?

Comment: It took 15 comments for you to tell us the one vital piece of information that would have been obvious if you had just posted your PHP form handler in the first place.  +1 on this answer, but -1 on the question.